# Errors when building with Xcode 7, Unity 5.2.3f1, iOS 9.1 base SDK

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to build a sample Unity app with Xcode 7, Unity 5.2.3f1, iOS 9.1 base SDK, but get these compile errors when trying to run the app in Xcode. I already set scripting backend = IL2CPP, Architecture = Universal, but it did not help.

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "_CloseZStream",
>   referenced from:
>         _DeflateStream_Dispose_m2_129 in Bulk_System_0.o
>         _DeflateStream_CloseZStream_m2_153 in Bulk_System_0.o
>        (maybe you meant: _DeflateStream_CloseZStream_m2_153)   "_CreateZStream", referenced from:
>         _DeflateStream_CreateZStream_m2_152 in Bulk_System_0.o
>        (maybe you meant: _DeflateStream_CreateZStream_m2_152)   "_Flush", referenced from:
>         _DeflateStream_Flush_m2_139 in Bulk_System_0.o
>         _DeflateStream_Flush_m2_154 in Bulk_System_0.o
>        (maybe you meant: _FtpDataStream_Flush_m2_546, _UnmanagedMemoryStream_Flush_m1_2462 , _NullStream_Flush_m1_2305 , _MemoryStream_Flush_m1_2229 , _FileStream_Flush_m1_2186 , _FileStream_FlushBuffer_m1_2191 , _FileStream_FlushBufferIfDirty_m1_2193 , _FileStream_FlushBuffer_m1_2192 , _XmlInputStream_Flush_m7_567 , _WebConnectionStream_Flush_m2_928 , _SynchronizedWriter_Flush_m1_2427 , _NetworkStream_Flush_m2_227 , _GZipStream_Flush_m2_162 ,
>   _DeflateStream_Flush_m2_139 , _StreamWriter_FlushBytes_m1_2354 , _DeflateStream_Flush_m2_154 , _TlsStream_Flush_m3_798 , _SslStream_Flush_m2_202 , _TextWriter_Flush_m1_2415 , _StreamWriter_Flush_m1_2353 , _SslStreamBase_Flush_m3_726 , _UnexceptionalStreamWriter_Flush_m1_2447 )   "_ReadZStream", referenced from:
>         _DeflateStream_ReadInternal_m2_134 in Bulk_System_0.o
>         _DeflateStream_ReadZStream_m2_155 in Bulk_System_0.o
>        (maybe you meant: _DeflateStream_ReadZStream_m2_155)   "_UnityADBannerViewFailedToLoad", referenced from:
>         -[UnityADBanner bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:] in iAD.o   "_UnityADBannerViewWasClicked", referenced from:
>         -[UnityADBanner bannerViewActionDidFinish:] in iAD.o   "_UnityADBannerViewWasLoaded", referenced from:
>         -[UnityADBanner bannerViewDidLoadAd:] in iAD.o   "_UnityADInterstitialADWasLoaded", referenced from:
>         -[UnityInterstitialAd interstitialAdDidLoad:] in iAD.o   "_UnityBindFramebuffer", referenced from:
>         _CreateSystemRenderingSurfaceGLES in GlesHelper.o
>         _DestroySystemRenderingSurfaceGLES in GlesHelper.o
>         _CreateRenderingSurfaceGLES in GlesHelper.o
>         _DestroyRenderingSurfaceGLES in GlesHelper.o
>         _CreateSharedDepthbufferGLES in GlesHelper.o
>         _CreateField in [Minesweeper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.popoko.minesweeper)
>         _PreparePresentGLES in GlesHelper.o   "_UnityBlitToBackbuffer", referenced from:
>         _PreparePresentGLES in GlesHelper.o   "_UnityCaptureScreenshot", referenced from:
>         _PreparePresentGLES in GlesHelper.o

Comment: Have the exact same problem; looks like something to do with 5.2.3f1. Everything worked on 5.2.2

Comment: Do these same errors occur with an empty project? The _CloseZStream (and friends) messages indicate that something is missing with the zlib native library that ships with Unity. It looks like there are also some graphics and Unity Ads related issues as well.

Comment: Only happens with unity 5.2.3, downgrading to 5.2.2 resolves this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this issue by checking "Symlink Unity Library" in Build Settings and made sure the build is for device, not simulator.

Comment: This works for me too, but is there a way to build for simulator?

Comment: Solved the issue for me. Thanks.

Comment: @gollumullog in Unity Build Settings

Comment: Running on device not simulator worked for me, is there any way to run on simulator?

Answer (score 1):

I had this error because my iOS device changed from an iphone 5 to a generic iOs device I assume because the cord wasn't high quality and it lost connection.

If XCode loses connection it tries to build for a generic device.

I just reconnected the phone and rebuilt fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get rid of this errors and run the game on the simulator:

In Unity go to **Edit > Project Settings > Player** it will open Player Settings in the inspector. Then select the IOS platform and **Other Settings >Target SDK > Simulator SDK**.

This solved the 200 linking errors saying "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64" and it works on the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

with Unity 5.4.03f I was getting **unity xcode undefined symbols for architecture arm64**

To solve it,
I have downgraded my unity to 5.3.5f1 personal . With player settings 
Scripting backend:IL2CPP and Architecture:Universal with xcode 7.3.1.

You can check size of libiPhone-lib.a to identify the difference of compiling with both unity versions.